# Plotting hclust only to the cut clusters, not every leaf

Tags: r, plot, dendrogram, hclust

I have an hclust tree with nearly 2000 samples. I have cut it to an appropriate number of clusters and would like to plot the dendrogram but ending at the height that I cut the clusters rather than all the way to every individual leaf. Every plotting guide is about coloring all the leaves by cluster or drawing a box, but nothing seems to just leave the leaves below the cut line out completely.

My full dendrogram looks like the following:

[image: Full Dendrogram]

I would like to plot it as if it stops where I've drawn the abline here (for example):

[image]

Comment: @Dave2e I have already used the cutree function to cut to the clusters I want, but as far as I can tell, there is no way to plot to where I cut it to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should get you started.  I suggest reading the help page for "dendrogram"

Here is the example from the help page:

```
hc <- hclust(dist(USArrests))
dend1 <- as.dendrogram(hc)
plot(dend1)
dend2 <- cut(dend1, h = 100)
plot(dend2$upper)
plot(dend2$upper, nodePar = list(pch = c(1,7), col = 2:1))
```

By performing the cut on the dendrogram object (not the hclust object) you can then plot the upper part of the dendrogram.  It will take a some work to replace the branch1, 2, 3, and 4 labels depending on your analysis.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, this has gotten me most of the way there, now I just have to figure out why my branch labels are misaligned!

-edit- Figured it out, I needed the "center" parameter, per the dendrogram page. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for this great answer! I am curious whether the groups correspond to what you'd receive from the `cutree()` function?

Comment: @KryštofChytrý, no it seems the group numbers are assigned randomly between `cut` & `cutree`