# how to plot hclust objects up to certain number of cuts?

Tags: r, dendrogram, hclust

I try to plot an hclust object. The plot looks ok but I would like to have a plot that doesn't go all the way down but stops at 5 cuts. I tried ylim but this doesn't change anything to the plot. My code is

```
library(datasets)
    data <- iris
dist <- dist(data, method= "euclidean")
hclust <- hclust(dist, method = "complete")
plot(hclust, ylim=4:8)
```

Answer (score 0):

here you can find the answer to your question [Plotting hclust only to the cut clusters, not every leaf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45472549/plotting-hclust-only-to-the-cut-clusters-not-every-leaf)

```
hclust <- cut(hclust, h = 100)
plot(hclust2$upper)
```