# cutting a dendogram in R USArrests dataset does not return a proper dendogram

Tags: r, hierarchical-clustering, dendrogram, hclust

I have been looking online for tutorial but the result is not correct

```
d <- dist(USArrests, method = "euclidean") # distance matrix
usarrests_hi_cluster <- hclust(d, method="complete") 

plot(usarrests_hi_cluster)
```

This works fine and I get the whole dendogram

but when I do the following to prune at certain height

```
my_dend<-cutree(usarrests_hi_cluster, h = 150)

print(my_dend)
```

only get a list of the states with a number

```
       Alabama         Alaska        Arizona       Arkansas 
             1              1              1              2 
    California       Colorado    Connecticut       Delaware 
             1              2              3              1 
       Florida        Georgia         Hawaii          Idaho 
             1              2              3              3 
      Illinois        Indiana           Iowa         Kansas 
             1              3              3              3 
      Kentucky      Louisiana          Maine       Maryland 
             3              1              3              1
```

I want to cut the dendogram at a certain height to get 3 clusters and plot it

I am tryingt to answer this question

(b) Cut the dendrogram at a height that results in three distinct clusters. Which states belong to which clusters?

Comment: Please review: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

See this question/answer for the same question but plotting the top of the tree: [Plotting hclust only to the cut clusters, not every leaf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45472549/plotting-hclust-only-to-the-cut-clusters-not-every-leaf/45473819#45473819)

What you are looking for are is plotting the lower branches.  The branch levels is stored as a list in the "$lower" variable of the data structure.

```
hc <- hclust(dist(USArrests))
#cut tree
dend2 <- cut(dend1, h = 150)
#cycle through the lower list and plot
lapply(dend2$lower, function(x){plot(x)})
```

To answer part (b): The output of `print(my_dend)` is showing which branch each state belongs to.